# Coherence for pseudomonads and their pseudoalgebras

Tags: ct.category-theory, monads, 2-categories, coherence

Let $\mathcal K$ be a bicategory. For every pseudomonad $T : \mathcal K \to \mathcal K$, does there exist a 2-monad $S : \mathcal C \to \mathcal C$, where $\mathcal C$ is a 2-category biequivalent to $\mathcal K$, such that the bicategory of pseudoalgebras $T\text{-}\mathrm{Alg}$ is biequivalent to the 2-category of pseudoalgebras $S\text{-}\mathrm{Alg}$?

That is, can we always choose to work with 2-monads rather than pseudomonads, so long as we consider their pseudoalgebras, rather than their strict algebras?

If this is true, does the statement continue to hold for the 2-category of strict algebras $S\text{-}\mathrm{Alg}_s$? ([Not every pseudoalgebra is equivalent to a strict algebra](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1005.1520.pdf), but this fact does not take into account changing the 2-monad: I imagine this is false, but it would be good to have a reference.)

Comment: A partial answer appears in Theorem 0.1 of https://www.math.uchicago.edu/~may/PAPERS/AddCat1.pdf With conditions on $K$ and $T$.