# Example of a pseudomonad on Cat whose pseudoalgebras are not the pseudoalgebras for a 2-monad

Tags: ct.category-theory, counterexamples, monads, 2-categories, coherence

For every pseudomonad $T$ on the 2-category of (locally small) categories $\mathbf{Cat}$, we can consider the 2-category of $T$-pseudoalgebras and pseudomorphisms $T\text{-PsAlg}_p$, which is equipped with a forgetful 2-functor $U_T : T\text{-PsAlg}_p \to \mathbf{Cat}$.

Is there an example of such a pseudomonad $T$ for which *there does not exist* a 2-monad $T'$ for which the 2-category of $T'$-pseudoalgebras and pseudomorphisms $T'\text{-PsAlg}_p$ is biequivalent to $T\text{-PsAlg}_p$, concretely over $\mathbf{Cat}$, in the sense that the following triangle commutes up to pseudomonad equivalence?

[image: The obvious triangle]

Intuitively, I am looking for an example of a pseudomonad on $\mathbf{Cat}$ that cannot be strictified into a 2-monad, or a proof that no such example exists. Note that it is certainly the case that a large class of pseudomonads *may* be strictified (e.g. as in the answer to [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/372354/2-monads-for-categories-with-a-class-of-colimits)).

(I have [previously asked](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/366783/coherence-for-pseudomonads-and-their-pseudoalgebras) a much more general question, but it seems plausible that this special case admits a simpler answer.)

Comment: Maybe symmetric or braided monoidal categories?

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე: these are the pseudoalgebras for the free strict symmetric/braided monoidal category 2-monads on $\mathbf{Cat}$.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by strict? For me it would mean strictly commutative, i. e. the symmetry isomorphisms being just identities.

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე: sorry, I meant to write "symmetric/braided strict monoidal category", i.e. the braiding is not strict.